# LessPHP 0.3.8 + Bootstrap 2.2.2: broken generated css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lessphp

I'm using LessPHP 0.3.8 + Bootstrap 2.2.2

The LessPHP seems to generate broken styles; see my example at http://alexeynekrasov.ru/test/lessphp.php

The left column is generated by LessPHP, the right column is generated by Bootstrap original site. Class `.btn` (and more) is broken.

Download and run my complete example: http://alexeynekrasov.ru/test/test.rar

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Update lessphp to the latest (0.3.9) and it works fine.